# request to localhost (Node.js server) returns ECONNREFUSED in travis ci

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, travis-ci, postman

I am developing a server using nodejs and express, I use newman package (postman's node library) for testing.
To run the tests I setup the server and then make requests using newman.
All works fine on my PC, but when I try to run the test on travis ci I get
`Error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000`.

How can I fix the issue? I think this is related to how travis ci handles VM, but can't find a solution.

[github repository](https://github.com/hellowitlab/IglooCloudServer/tree/endpoints): the tests are in the postman folder and be sure to look at the endpoints branch
[travis ci log](https://travis-ci.org/hellowitlab/IglooCloudServer)

Comment: I'm guessing the environment doesn't want you to bind your server to port 3000. I'm not familiar with how travis ci works, but sometimes remote environments store the port they want you to use in `process.env.PORT`. Have you tried that?

Comment: The server only uses port 3000 if process.env.PORT does not exist

Comment: Hello Andrea, could you find a solution ? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Port 3000 must be in use by some other process in your local PC.
Please try changing port number